# Google Drive upload fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, google-drive-api

I have a method that checks if my file exists on the drive and if not, it uploads one and adds permission.
This method worked while testing the first time and Update requests worked on the file to.
After deleting all existing files in my drive the upload stopped working, the responsebody is null and if I look at it in viddler the requestbody is also empty. 
(the file is a valid docx)
I am using the following code:

```
DriveService service = Google_SDK.Authentication.AppFlowMetadata.BuildServerDriveService();

Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file;
var items = service.Files.List().Execute().Items.ToLookup(a => a.OriginalFilename = doc.Name + " (" + doc.Id + ".docx)");
if (items.Count > 0)
{
    // This worked while testing:
        //string fileId = items.FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault().Id;
        //FilesResource.UpdateRequest uploadRequest = service.Files.(body, fileId, stream, "application/vnd.google-apps.document");
        //uploadRequest.Convert = true;
        //uploadRequest.Upload();

    file = items.FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault();
}
else
{

    Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
    body.Title = doc.Name + " (" + doc.Id + ".docx)";
    body.OriginalFilename = doc.Name + " (" + doc.Id + ".docx)";
    body.Editable = true;
    body.Shared = false;
    body.WritersCanShare = false;
    body.Copyable = false;
    body.Description = doc.Notes;
    body.MimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";

    byte[] byteArray = doc.DocxContent; // valid byteArray
    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

    FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload uploadRequest = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "application/vnd.google-apps.document");
    uploadRequest.Convert = true;
    uploadRequest.Upload();

    file = uploadRequest.ResponseBody; // No errors or exceptions but returns null

    PermissionsResource.InsertRequest permissionRequest = service.Permissions.Insert(new Permission()
    {
        Role = "writer",
        Type = "user",
        EmailAddress = "user@domain.com",
        Value = "user@domain.com"

    }, file.Id); // file.Id fails becase file equals null
    permissionRequest.Execute();
}
```

I really do not see what I am doing wrong and why this worked the first time.
Thank you in advance.

Edit:

---

I've been debugging some other parts of my project and I found out that the changes still exist, this seems logical that any deletion is saved as a change for version controll.
Maybe that has something to do with my problems?

Also I forgot to mention that the deletion of all the files is done by code and the drive used is not a gmail account but an *.apps.googleusercontent.com account.
The code I used to remove all the files:

```
DriveService service = Google_SDK.Authentication.DriveServiceProvider.Service;
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();

FileList listResponse = listRequest.Execute();
int amount = listResponse.Items.Count();
foreach(Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File f in listResponse.Items.AsQueryable()){
   FilesResource.DeleteRequest deleteRequest = service.Files.Delete(f.Id);
   deleteRequest.Execute();
}

HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(String.Format("Removed {0} items.",amount));
return response;
```

Edit 2:

---

I've created a completely new document in my system and tried uploading it to the google drive. This was succesfull! After deleting the new document from the drive I got the same behavior as described above, an empty responsebody while uploading.

So even though I removed the old document it still recognizes that it is the same document that used to be on the drive.

Does somebody know a way to prevent this?

Comment: You are not using the assigned `file` variable in the `if` block?!?

Comment: I do, "file" is the existing file if it exists.
In the else clause I define a new File called "body", I try to upload this to the drive wich should return a new File instance with an Id assigned in the uploadRequest.ResponseBody, I assign that to the "file" variable so that I can use the instance after the if/else statement like I would if It already existed.
The problem is that the ResponseBody is null.